# React Native: How to get values from a loop into a hooks useState

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

Aim: to read a certain set of objects (as strings) from async storage and put them into a useState object.

Background: I'm storing an indeterminate number of bluetooth peripheral objects into async storage e.g. a heart rate monitor, a cadence sensor, a speed sensor.

When my app starts I use useEffect to go and grab these strings, JSON.parse them and then I want to add them to a useState object: const [peripherals, setPeripherals] = useState([])

So I can loop through my particular keys and get the value from async storage, but then I know I can't add to the state from within the loop.

But for the life of me I can't see how I can determine when the asynchronous loop has finished and then update my state. I can create an ordinary JavaScript array and update it fine, and I know about useEffect for responding to a change in variable, but I just cannot see how to make it work together or how to refactor my code to make it work.

I'd be grateful for insights.

Here is some skeleton code

```
const [peripherals, setPeripherals] = useState([])                      
const plist = []   //temp array

useEffect( () => {
  //loop through all the keys in async storage
  const getAllSavedPeripherals = async () => {
    let keys = []
    try {
      keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
      if (keys !== null) { <--this happens when keys return,yes?
        keys.forEach(key => {
         if (key.startsWith('ble')) {
           getPeripheral(key)
         }
        })
      }   
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('GM: get all keys error : ', e)
    }
  }

  const getPeripheral = async (key) => {
    try {
      let p = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      plist.push( JSON.parse(p) )        //<--this works fine(?)
    }
    catch (e) {
     console.log('GM: get key data error : ', e)
    }
  }
  getAllSavedPeripherals()

  ...
}, [])
```

My problem is that I'm sure I don't understand how to work with asynchronous code properly. I'm sure I could refactor the above code somewhat, but my attempts to put the let p = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key) into the getAllSavedPeripherals function failed (it didn't like the second await inside the loop.)

However, the main point is that how can I know when this loop has completed? When I know this I can then setPeripherals(plist)

If I try and use useEffect( () => { setPeripherals(plist) },[plist] ) it still to my mind hits the same problem as it is just updating the state in a loop?

It really does have me stumped.

I have searched and searched and read, but nothing seems to match my use case. (I'm convinced that web searching has deteriorated in the last couple of years?), so please be gentle as you flame me :)

Test data in plist:

[image: My plist]

Answer (score 0):

So, I left this issue and worked on something else and then realised I could refactor the problem and use the async-storage multi get.

Here is my code fragment for those who are interested.

However, I'd still be interested in what I could have done using the original idea, I suspect the issue might come up again ;)

```
    const getAllSavedPeripherals = async () => {
      //get an array from all keys of those starting with 'ble'  //this is just with my application
      let keys = []
      let values = []
      try {
        keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        if (keys !== null) {
          keys = keys.filter(key => key.startsWith('ble'))
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('GM: get all keys error : ', e)
      }
      //I have an array of keys so now multi-get and process
      try {
        if (keys !== null) {
          values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
          console.log('values', values)  
          // //getting back arrays of arrays, need to convert to objects
          plist = []
          values.forEach(v => {
            plist.push({ id: v[0].substring(3), peripheral: JSON.parse(v[1]).peripheral })
          })
          console.log(peripherals)
          console.log(plist)
          setPeripherals(plist)  <-- now that I have an array I can simply update the peripherals state - yippee.
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('GM: get all data error : ', e)
      }
    }
    getAllSavedPeripherals()
```